# Flash messages not showing in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, connect-flash

I can't get flash messages to turn up.  Here's how I'm calling them in my routes:

```
middlewareObj.isLoggedIn = function(req, res, next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }
    req.flash("error", "You must be logged in to do that.");
    res.redirect("/login");
};
```

Here's my relevant app.js set up:

```
var express                 = require("express"),
    app                     = express(),
    bodyParser              = require("body-parser"),
    mongoose                = require("mongoose"),
    passport                = require("passport"),
    flash                   = require("connect-flash");

app.use(flash());
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
    res.locals.success = req.flash("success");
    next();
});
```

And my template code looks like this:

```
<% if(error && error.length > 1){ %>
    <%console.log(error)%>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <%= error %>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

Totally stuck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
<% if(error && error.length > 1){ %>
```

needs to be

```
<% if(error && error.length >0){ %>
```